# Why Does this SFML Code Act like an App, But Does Not Create a Window?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion, macos-catalina

Stack Overflow. I come to you in a time of great need.

I am starting to learn C++, after learning Python, and I want to learn C++ in an entreating way; that is, by making games with SFML. I am following a book which you can find [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1838648577). I use MacOs Catalina, and Clion with Cmake. The problem is that, when using a basic example, listed below, SFML does not create a window. (Sorry for my use of using namespace)

My Code:

```
// Include important C++ libraries here
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

// Make code easier to type with "using namespace"
using namespace sf;

int main()
{

    // Create a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);

    // Create and open a window for the game
    // RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!", Style::Fullscreen);

    // Low res code
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!");

    // Create a texture to hold a graphic on the GPU
    Texture textureBackground;

    // Load a graphic into the texture
    textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");

    // Create a sprite
    Sprite spriteBackground;

    // Attach the texture to the sprite
    spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);

    // Set the spriteBackground to cover the screen
    spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);


    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        /*
        ****************************************
        Handle the players input
        ****************************************
        */

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        /*
        ****************************************
        Update the scene
        ****************************************
        */


        /*
        ****************************************
        Draw the scene
        ****************************************
        */

        // Clear everything from the last frame
        window.clear();

        // Draw our game scene here
        window.draw(spriteBackground);

        // Show everything we just drew
        window.display();


    }

    return 0;
}
```

An image of what happens when I build and execute is below
[image: The Image]

I tried to reinstall SFML, make the window smaller (the book suggests that I create a smaller, 960-pixel-wide VideoMode object and then window.draw() the original 1920/1080 picture*, but this did not work), re-build the project, execute it from XCode, and copy the SFML.dll files into my main project directory (and also I checked for my project directory).

Is this normal? Do you know how I can fix it? Notice how it takes up my screen as if it were the app which I am currently using. Thank you for your time.

- As a footnote, I ran some other SFML examples to check the correctness of my SFML installation. The ran successfully.

Comment: I recommend that you start simpler than the code you show. Just create a window, wait a few seconds, then close it and exit the program. When you get that to work, add the event loop. Then add the sprite. Etc., until you have your full program.

Comment: Yes... this is the result after I finish the first chapter. The weird thing is that this does not ever create a window, or display a sprite. I still wonder why this happens. Thanks though! @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are missing the event loop. Events have to be polled for window to work properly.

```cpp
sf::Event event;

// Then in your main loop...
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
  // Handle events.
}
```

Comment: Can't believe my book didn't mention that... smh